# microk8s OIDC with keycloak

Tags: microk8s

I would like to protect microk8s behind an identity server (keycloak) with OIDC.

Where do i have to set the configurations to use my keycloak server as a Kubernetes Identity Server?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with microk8s (1.21/stable) and after configuring the apiserver for the oidc configuration, dex in my case, the kubelite doesn't start:

```
 vi /var/snap/microk8s/2210/args/kube-apiserver
 #Added these oidc parameters:
--oidc-issuer=https://oidc-url.example.com
--oidc-auth-client=oidc-auth-client 
--oidc-username-claim=email 
--oidc-groups-claim=groups 
--oidc-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
```

After that, I restarted the kubelite, starting from 1.20 I think, all the kubernetes controllers with apiserver and db are provided by kubelite, but it doesn't start.

```
systemctl stop snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service
systemctl start snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service  
journactl -u  snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service 
mag 19 18:41:29 microk8s-test-01 microk8s.daemon-kubelite[599787]: Error: 
unknown flag: --oidc-issuer
mag 19 18:41:29 microk8s-test-01 microk8s.daemon-kubelite[599787]: F0519 18:41:29.537492  599787 daemon.go:67] API Server exited unknown flag: --oidc-issuer
mag 19 18:41:29 microk8s-test-01 systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
mag 19 18:41:29 microk8s-test-01 systemd[1]: snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

From the logs above, the apiserver doesn't recognize the oidc-issuer parameter.

Best

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

The miccrok8s snap package stores its config files in the $SNAP_DATA directory, which normally points to `/var/snap/microk8s/current` [(docs)](https://microk8s.io/docs/configuring-services).

You need to edit the kube-apiserver config. Add the needed flags, which is described in the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuring-the-api-server)